# create authentication web service with token

Tags: node.js

I'm working with express in order to create web services I'm a beginner and now I need to make an authentication service for my application with mysql and express with tokens someone could help me

Comment: this is what you need: https://github.com/raysk4ever/AuthApi_Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

try using jwt package or you can use passport.

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: https://github.com/didinj/node-express-mongoose-passport-jwt-rest-api-auth

Comment: you can use either token based or session based authentication or combined.